# Open any product page in new IE tab

Tags: product, magento-1.9, catalog

Just a quick question about opening any product in new IE tab.
For example
Go to [this site](http://www.ctmusicshop.com/store/product/Fender-396381-th.html)
Then try to click on any product, new IE tab will be created with the product page.

Is there any setting relate to this request?
Or adding a piece of code?

Comment: Where do I find that a tag? I also want that some of my products can open in new window, but dont know where to find that line that you are talking about.
Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very Simple you have to add teh HTML code in `<a>` tag. There are not lot of coding just add an attribute in `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="http://www.ctmusicshop.com/store/product/view/Fender_Standard_Stratocaster_Maple_Fingerboard-11270713-th.html" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

You have to use "target="_blank"" Attribute in `<a>` so when any user click on that it will open a product in new window each time.

See my above example. so when you click on link then it will open a link in new tab rather then same window.

Let me know still you are facing any problem then.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have done a code modification follow your advise. Everything work as expect

Comment: If you use the `target="_blank"` code be sure to add the `rel="nofollow noopenner"` tag as well [here's why](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working for me. The system throws this error "Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://)"